# How to match unique key and foreign key in include instead of primary key and foreign key in Sequelize

Tags: sql-server, node.js, sequelize.js

There are two tables [bow detail and item detail]. I'm actually done the association between two tables

```
 var BomDetail = sequelize.define('BomDetail', {
        bomId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'bom_id',
            unique: true
        },
        createdBy: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'created_by'
     },
BomDetail.hasMany(models.ItemDetail, {
     foreignKey: 'bomId',
     sourceKey: 'bomId',
     onDelete: 'cascade'
});

var ItemDetail = sequelize.define('ItemDetail', {
        itemId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'item_id',
            unique: true
        },
        holdDate: {
            type: DataTypes.DATE,
            field: 'hold_date',
        },
        bomId: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING,
            field: 'bom_id'
        },
ItemDetail.associate = function(models) {
        ItemDetail.belongsTo(models.BomDetail, {
            foreignKey: 'bomId',
            targetKey: 'bomId',
            onDelete: 'cascade'
        });
    };
```

When i do

```
Models.ItemDetail.findAll({
include: {
model: Models.BomDetail
}
})
```

normal result that is bomdetail inside the item detail will come

```
{
"id": 3,
"itemId": "2397saf8enaeflk8",
"productId": "afsggfg14fhg43t",
"productName": "Siemens meter",
"quantity": 3,
"followUpDate": "2018-05-15T18:30:00.000Z",
"leadTime": 10,
"releaseDate": "2018-05-20T18:30:00.000Z",
"holdDate": "2018-05-31T18:30:00.000Z",
"bomId": "azcpspp02_07141700_07_00_M00",
"status": "hold",
"created_at": "2018-05-14T09:20:15.658Z",
"updated_at": "2018-05-14T09:20:15.658Z",
"BomDetail": {
"id": 50,
"bomId": "azcpspp02_07141700_07_00_M00",
"createdBy": "azcpspp02",
"createdByName": "Siemens BLR -nry85322",
"bomCreatedDate": "2018-02-26T00:00:00.000Z",
"soldToAcc": "30000006",
"status": "hold",
"created_at": "2018-05-11T11:58:46.267Z",
"updated_at": "2018-05-11T11:58:46.267Z"
}
},
```

but when i do

```
Models.BomDetail.findAll({
include: {
model: Models.ItemDetail:
}
})
```

Error will come..
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'azcpspp02_07141700_07_00_M00' to data type int.

it compares primay key that is generated by sequelize in BomDetail table and foreign key of ItemDetail
like
...LEFT OUTER JOIN [lta_item_detail] AS [ItemDetails] ON **[BomDetail].[id] = [ItemDetails].[bom_id];**

But i want to compare unique key(bomId) of BomDetail table and corresponding foreign key of ItemDetail table (BomId)..

(i.e)...LEFT OUTER JOIN [lta_item_detail] AS [ItemDetails] ON **[BomDetail].[bom_id] = [ItemDetails].[bom_id];**

What should I do for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the bomId from ItemDetail Model and do required false to apply left outer join.

```
Models.BomDetail.findAll({
    include: {
       model: Models.ItemDetail,
       required : false
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try defining source key as field name, so that associate will work accordingly.

```
BomDetail.hasMany(models.ItemDetail, {
    foreignKey: 'bomId',
    sourceKey: 'bom_id',
    onDelete: 'cascade'
});
```